# Comparing the experimental and calculated UV/vis spectra for ethene

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, spectroscopy

I am trying to compute UV/Vis absorption spectrum for Ethene using Gaussian 09.

I created the ethene molecule in GaussView 5, and cleaned it. Then I optimized the molecule and checked if I got the minimum energy conformation with the following:

```
# freq=noraman cphf=noread b3lyp/6-31g(d) geom=connectivity formcheck 
 integral=grid=ultrafine scf=maxcycle=1000
```

Next I performed the energy calculation as follows:

```
# td b3lyp/6-31g(d) geom=connectivity
```

As a result I got a single peak with the maximum at 134 nm (see picture below) which seems to be way off from what I googled around on the Internet, which is like 173 nm or 180 nm.
[image]

Can anyone please help me figure out if I have done it correctly and whether I am way off the experimental data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In short, there are two obvious problems with the setup OP uses for TD-DFT calculations:

1. B3LYP functional is *not* a good choice for TD-DFT.
2. 6-31G(d) basis is usually too *small*.

At M06-2X/Def2-TZVP level I get a maximum at ~160 nm, which, taking the accuracy of the TD-DFT approximations into account, is close enough to the experimental value.

Comment: Thank you @Wildcat. I tried to redo the calculation according to your suggestion. I just took the molecule optimized at b3lyp/6-31g(d) and calculated the energy as follows: # td M062X/Def2TZVP geom=connectivity. I got the maximum 158.53 nm, so close to what you kindly reported. I wonder however if it's OK what I did in terms of optimizing the geometry at a different level than the one used to do the TD calculation for UV/Vis spectra? Looks like it works here. Do you think I do not need to reoptimize all of my molecules then?

Comment: B3LYP/6-31G* might be a bad choice for a lot of calculations but it is not to be doomed a priori. We calculate a lot with it and reach acceptable accuracy. It always depends on the molecule that you are investigating. M06-2X for example does not give acceptable excitation energies for my complexes. Not even with triple zeta bs while B3LYP/6-31G* is way better for us.

Comment: B3LYP/6-31G* might occasionally spit out some good numbers for excitation energies, right, but I would not trust this level of theory anyway since even when it works fine, it is very likely just the result of a fortunate cancellation of errors.

Comment: @RicardoMoreno, B3LYP/6-31G* geometry of ethene should be good enough, so that there is no need for reoptimization.

Comment: @pH13-YetanotherPhilipp That is because M06-2X is not meant to be used for excitation energies, only ground-state properties such as thermochemistry and non-covalent interactions.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon, why do you say that "M06-2X is not meant to be used for excitation energies"? It is one of the best hybrids according to benchmarks (10.1002/qua.24438).

Answer (score 6):

For smaller molecules like ethene, the [webbook](http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/name-ser.html) by NIST is a good source of experimental data.  Search results for ethene in particular [here](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=ethene&Units=SI) yield both a figure of a vacuum UV spectrum, indicating an absorption maximum centred around 160-165 nm with $\log \epsilon$ of about 4.2, as well with a primary literature reference (Platt, J.R.; Price, W.C., J. Chem. Phys., 1949, 17, 466). 
Of course, other databases like Scifinder/Chemical Abstracts by the American Chemical Society may indidicate more recent data.  A specialized compilation, more suitable for ethene in particular, is the MPI-Mainz UV/VIS Spectral Atlas of Gaseous Molecules of Atmospheric Interest [here](http://satellite.mpic.de/spectral_atlas), with an entry about [ethene](http://satellite.mpic.de/spectral_atlas/cross_sections/Alkenes,dienes+radicals/Alkenes/CH2=CH2.spc).

Side note: NIST database equally offers access to other thermophysical data (like Vibrational and/or electronic energy levels) potentially of interest for you, too.

Addendum:  With the searchable [Computational Chemistry Comparison and Benchmark DataBase](http://cccbdb.nist.gov/introx.asp), NIST equally hosts *numerous* results of calculations of energies and structures for small molecules.  This that may serve as a valuable reference, comparing the methods with each other, as well against experimentally determined data.

Comment: Dear @Buttonwood, thank you so much for your guidance and the awesome links! By the way, do you think that the `# td M062X/Def2TZVP` level as suggested by Wildcat (and it seems to be working fine for ethene) will be good enough for UV/Vis computation for larger molecules, let's say 20-25 heavy atoms like carbon, and only a few oxygens or nitrogens around?

Comment: @Ricardo Moreno You are wellcome.  Yet: My practice in computational chemistry is too limited to provide you sound advice about the method / basis set to be deployed other than too look out how similar questions were solved by others in the field.  Drawing a structure, (pre)optimising here and then with a force field & PM3 as a starting point / comparision e. g. for powder diffraction differs on what your question adresses and (in terms of computational cost) is at least a league below b3lyp and other hybrid functionals.

Comment: @RicardoMoreno Take a tour d'horizon in CCBDB just discovered.  (Ethene is present, too.)